# Is ContainsAll in the Mongo 2.1 rc0 driver for C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Prior to the 2.0 re-write there was a ContainsAll extension method on IEnumerable which would I suspect map to $all in the final mongo query.

For some reason I'm not seeing it in the latest 2.1 RC0 bits. If it's dropped, or just missing, is there some way to Inject that $all clause back into the IQueryable?

I realize the ContainsAll extension method is defined in the LinqToMongo class, which unfortunately is now/still in the [MongoDb.Driver.Legacy assembly](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.1/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_LinqToMongo_ContainsAll__1.htm).  Setting a reference to that legacy assembly and then trying to use the ContainsAll extension method results in the exception "Unsupported Filter".

Yes I can use the Legacy Assembly exclusively but will then be missing out a number of things, not the least being the async/await features.

Comment: You should be able to do this with [`FilterDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>.All`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_All.htm)

Comment: Certainly but I have a development team that's transitioning from MS SqlServer and so I've wanted to say with Linq as a query framework since it's what they are familiar with.  This is why the RC release of 2.1 was so exciting.  Unless there's a way of folding in FilterDefinitionBuilders into a IMongoQuerable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MongoCSharpDriver 2.1.0-rc1 the $all operator is supported.
[See the Issue Resolution here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1432)

Comment: So nice when taking the trouble to file a JIRA actually gets the problem fixed!

Comment: @JohnnyHK I was blown away